# Simple game development with Java and LWJGL

Tags: java, opengl, game-engine, lwjgl

of course I'm not the first one to develop such a game. But I want to become professional with game development within in the next years. I want to implement a shoot'em up game. It is not my first one. I developed one in Turbo Pascal 6.0 in 1998. But without using OOP. This game will be my 2nd shoot'em up in Java, but the 1st one using LWJGL. It will be implemented in 2D.

I want to keep it quite simple. But there are some features I wanna implement. I plan to make 10 Levels. The player has a spaceship he can move in four directions(up, down, left right). The ship has a double-laser which can be shoot only upwards. The ship can only be moved, I don't plan any rotation.

One level has several enemies of the same kind. The enemies are also spaceships. The most simple ships just move downwards. The also are firing single or double laser bullets. There lasers have a min. and max. frequency. I want to define a mathematical function which defines how possible it is to have a frequency(between min and max).

The ship speed is constant within an enemy (and level). In later levels the enemies gain double or 2,5x speed. Enemies in later levels have lasers which seek the player's ship. I plan to have one enemy in lategame which has growing laser bullets.

There are no other obstacles within each level. Each level has some stars as a background. First I want to implement a static background, later I plan to make 3 kinds of stars which are moving at different speed.

The player's ship's laser does single or double damage, depending on if one or two bullets hit. The enemies have some hitpoints til they die. The player ship's has also some hitpoints til it dies.

I want to have two kinds of explosions(consisting of some concetrally spreading ellipses with colors from yellow to red). A small explosion  for laser hits. And a big explosion von ship destruction.

My friend told me that there is a function which is called 60 times per second which renders the graphical objects. So I think within this function I draw all the objects and do nothing more. But of course the coordinates of ships and lasers change.

So I am think if I should use threads or not.

If I would use threads I would assign every ship which appears concurrently to one thread, and make threads for every laser and later for the dynamic background. In another thread I would wait for keyboard input.

Of course there is a tradeoff between using threads or not.

Using threads leeds to realistic parallelism and may be necessary to have a flowing game. But avoiding threads would lead to simpler programming, not regarding concurrent access to data. So I ask all  of you experienced game developers. Would you use threads or not? And If you would use them, is my conception good or not. And why? I am also happy about other practical hints.

Thank you!

Comment: Too broad... also wall of text, and a lot of off-topic stuff. Game design concept discussion would probably be better suited for [GameDevSE](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Too broad indeed. Like everything in the world of software engineering, you can't apply a pattern and always stick to it. It depends fully on the game you're building. Applying threading for pong is pretty much senseless. Applying threading in a game which has to manage the AI of thousands of computer controlled entities: a far better idea. NOTE: on a multi-core or multi-cpu system of course.

Comment: There are 2 important things to note: (1) A game can be made one one thread + listeners for keyboard input etc; such a game will appear identical to a game that is multithreaded (but will not use all the available CPU power). (2) Having more threads (that are doing significant work) will slow down your program significantly. If you are running on a duel core you want at most 4 threads

Comment: @RichardTingle Although unless it's a turn-based game or incredibly trivial, I'd find it hard to make a game that wouldn't have a separate dedicated thread constantly updating the game state/rendering the screen etc.

Comment: @CeilingGecko yet for over three decades programmers managed to do that just fine even on computers which had 1/1000th the resources of today's mobile phones. Perhaps you simply need to look around a bit more to learn how to do it, it would be a rich addition to your knowledge pool and a better game programmer.

Comment: @CeilingGecko I made space invaders single threaded as an excercise. It was all very simple; just an update loop and a paint loop (both within a larger loop). From there you could make anything (but of course you would start wanting the additional performance from multithreading). I also made a full 3D game where my part was single threaded (but I think the underlying engine used some threading + of course the GPU can be considered parrallel) before making it multithreaded for performance

Comment: I wanted to post all this in the official LWJGL forum but I am waiting for a registration mail for hours. Of course everything which is similar to space invaders works single threaded. But I once learned not to do all the calculation in the same method as the painting. But I just thought when complicating all the calculation it may slow down using a single thread. Thanks for the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any game can be made using a single thread plus event listeners. This would use an update loop to update each object every frame. In the simplest terms this can be a loop with a `Thread.sleep` in it although [swing timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) are a more advanced technique

```
int framesPerSecond=60;
double frameTime=1000.0/framesPerSecond; 

while(running){
    for(Updatable updatable:updatables){
         //should actually measure the frame time since it would actually be 
         //exactly this. System.nanoTime() can be used for this
         updatable.update(frameTime); 

         //depending on your graphics library each updatable object may be given
         //the opportunity to render itself here

    }

    renderFrame(); //render frame as appropriate for your graphics library
    Thread.sleep(frameTime); 
}
```

The one thing you critically must not have are many freewheeling threads each doing its own thing with no co-ordination. This is almost impossible to write without bugs (and is very inefficient anyway).

## Using appropriate numbers of threads

Within the update loop it is often possible to break down the update into independant parts that do not effect each other. In this case you can give each part to a thread ([thread pools](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/pools.html) are excellent for making this process simpler). Annother nice use for threads is preparing things that will be needed for the game soon but not right now; such as generating the next level.

However, the rule with multithreading is **do not have significantly more threads than cores**. Each thread has non trivial overhead but once you have more threads than cores you are (usually) not increasing your execution speed at all. So for example a program on a duel core should have at most 4 threads doing significant work. A quad core should have at most 8 etc.

Comment: This is an excellent post, but I have a question: did you deliberately leave out an example call to render the frame (in which case I would suggest to put it in for completeness), or do you update and render in one go?

Comment: @Gimby I left it out primarily because its precise form is somewhat depandant on the library and I wanted to keep it focused on the threading issue. I note the tags contain LWJGL but my 3D library of choice is JMonkey (I'm a scene graph man) so I would almost certainly get it wrong if I included a LWJGL call. Feel free to edit it in though

Comment: I was more aiming at keeping it API-agnostic; like you have a generic updatable.update(), so to can a simple renderFrame() be in the example without having to further specify how it does that exactly. Its only to illustrate after all. Your code comment is good enough though :)

Comment: @Gimby Thats actually a very good idea.  Edited

Comment: I think I will implement it serial threaded at first. And later on I will break up the update part into independent parts. Then I will compare runtime.

Comment: @user2039740 That is often the wisest way; bugs are far easier to find in a single threaded program but (used correctly) multithreaded programs can be faster